# latex and unicode: how to write special symbols of other scripts, or import symbols?

Tags: unicode, latex

I couldn't find the answer to this question in SO. I'll try to explain.

I'm writing some text in which I need to change scripts very often. Say I want to write some unicode character (not in the character script, but more in the transliteration of it, say \'a for á). What is the best way to do this in scripts such as indic, chinese, etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Xetex](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=XeTeX), "a typesetting system based on a merger of Donald Knuth's TeX system with Unicode and modern font technologies."

Answer (score 0):

\usepackage{CJK} for Chinese. Although, XeLaTeX might be your best bet, since you are either going to have to use the CJK font from latex, which i understand is pretty ugly, or make the font files then add them to your fontmap file, etc etc.